# Rails - Nested Forms will create, but information won't be saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, fields-for, nested-form-for

I've been struggling to get my nested form to save the users' inputs. The "outer" form saves the information perfectly. The "inner", or nested, one creates a new object, and passes hidden-field informations, but all other values are "nil".

Each order has one or more date_orders, and you should be able to create the first one through this form.

My code follows. Please help me spot anything that might be causing that. I've browsed StackOverflow extensively.

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.date_orders.build
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.date_orders.build
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Success"
        redirect_to current_user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(
        :user_id, :description, date_order_attributes: 
            [:id, :order_date, :time_start, :time_end, :order_id])
end
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :date_orders, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :date_orders
end
```

date_order.rb

```
class DateOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

routes.rb --> date_orders is not mentioned in the routes. Is that a problem?

orders/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<!-- form_for fields FIELDS -->
<%= fields_for :date_orders do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.hidden_field :order_id, :value => @order.id %> <- THIS WORKS

    <%= builder.label :date %>
    <%= builder.date_field :order_date %>

    <%= builder.label :starting_time %>
    <%= builder.time_field :time_start %>

    <%= builder.label :ending_time %>
    <%= builder.time_field :time_end %>


<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Request", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: example of a hash that is created:

```
<DateOrder id: 9, order_date: nil, time_start: nil, time_end: nil, order_id: 29, created_at: "2016-04-29 22:43:18", updated_at: "2016-04-29 22:43:18">enter code here`
```

Comment: `@order.date_orders.build` in the `#create` action is unnecessary. It builds a new object from scratch, which is not what you want - you only want to save the user input. Can you paste here an example for the `params` hash the `#create` action receives after submitting in the UI input that is not working properly for you?

Comment: Also, you don't need the hidden field.

Comment: Oh, you have a typo in the `permit`. It should be `date_orders_attributes` in plural. Please look at the server log `rails s` keeps spitting out - all non permitted attributes should get a warning. Make sure you don't have any.

Comment: Just added a hash that is created.

Comment: I meant the `params` hash the controller action `#create` receive, not a newly created date order object.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blabla==", "order"=>{"user_id"=>"104", "school_id"=>"1", "district_id"=>"1", "facility_school_id"=>"9", "purpose"=>"Fundraising", "attendees"=>"Closed group", "attendees_number"=>"15", "description"=>"example fundraiser", "full_name"=>"Guilherme de Souza", "user_group"=>"Example High School student", "email"=>"guilherme@email.com", "phone_number"=>"9999999999", "occupation"=>""}, "date_orders"=>{"order_id"=>"", "order_date"=>"2016-07-25", "time_start"=>"16:30", "time_end"=>"18:30"}, "commit"=>"Request to book"}.

Comment: It does include them, under `date_orders` instead of `date_orders_attributes`. This is very weird. It should add the `_attributes` suffix as soon as it sees it is a `accepts_nested_attributes`. The code that is responsible for it is in actionview gem under lib/helpers/form_helper.rb. right after `def fields_for` there is a line saying `if nested_attributes_association?(record_name)`. If you're using `pry` and `pry-byebug` to debug, put a `binding.pry` there and try to see why it's not getting into this if.

Comment: I had a similar issue once when instead of sending an ActiveRecord object to the form I sent a delegator object that didn't do a great job delegating the `respond_to?` method. Are you sure in your real life situation you're sending a plain `@order = Order.new` to the form in the `#new` action?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts of how to debug these type of issues:

1. Take a look at the server logs (the terminal window where you ran `rails s`). If strong parameters `permit` drops non-permitted attributes, you'll see a warning there. Make sure you don't have any typos, such as in your case (using `date_order_attributes` instead of `date_orders_attributes`).
2. Submit form input in the UI that does not work, take a look at the server logs and find the `params` hash being sent. You can then debug your code by simply going to console and pasting the relevant keys from the params hash you send to `Order.new`. E.g.: `Order.new(params['order'])`

A few changes I would make in your code:

1. Remove `@order.date_orders.build` from the `#create` action. This is something useful for `#new` to display an empty date order, but not in `#create` where you want to fully rely on the user input.
2. Remove `<%= builder.hidden_field :order_id, :value => @order.id %>`. Rails does not need it. When you told rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for :date_orders`, it simply added a default `date_orders_attributes=` method to your model. When you send a hash that looks like `hash = {order_title: 'my_title', date_orders_attributes: {order_date: '...'}}`, to `Order.new(hash)`, ActiveRecord sends the `date_orders_attributes` part of the hash to that method **on that newly created order instance**. I.e., this method already knows your child date orders belong to the order instance, so it is unnecessary.